Find the value of x for which the diagonal of the parallelepiped has the minimum length.
the problem
A rectangular parallelepiped has the dimensions $x-2,7-x,x-3$. Find the value of x for which the diagonal of the parallelepiped has the minimum length.
my idea
So we basically have to find $?$, where $$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(7-x)^2+(x-3)^2}\geq ?$$
From here I tried using some well known inequality like HM-AM,Minkovski, CBS, but none of them got some useful info...
ALso ,if it helps, $$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(7-x)^2+(x-3)^2} = \sqrt{3x^2-24x+62}$$
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Since your question did not contain the pre-calculus tag, I wonder if you have been studying derivatives.  Note that if $~f(x) = \sqrt{g(x)},~$ where $~g(x) \geq 0~$ throughout the domain of the function $~g,~$ then you can minimize $~f(x)~$ by (instead) minimizing $~g(x).~$ This simplifies the problem.  I suggest examining the behavior of $~g(x)~$ throughout its domain by specifically computing and examining the behavior of $~g'(x)~$ and $~g''(x).$

$$\sqrt{3x^2-24x+62}=\sqrt{3x^2-2×\frac{12}{\sqrt 3}×\sqrt{3} x +\frac{144}{3}+62-\frac{144}{3}}\\
=\sqrt{\bigg(\sqrt 3 x-\frac{12}{\sqrt 3}\bigg)^2+14}$$
Hence if $x=\frac{12}{3}=4$, we get minimum diagonal value of $\sqrt{14}$.
Method 2:-
$$y=3x^2-24x+62\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=6x-24=0$$ for maximum and minimum values. The quadratic eqn has a positive coefficient of $x^2$, so it only has a defined minima at $x=4$.
Thus $y=14\implies \sqrt y=\sqrt {14}$.

Complete the square inside the square root:
$$\sqrt{3x^2-24x+62}=\sqrt{3(x-4)^2+14}$$
The minimum value of this expression is $\boxed{\sqrt{14}}$ with $x = 4$.

ANS root 14 = 3.74 , for detailed steps,  click the link

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Ok , i try carlos
